# Spring web application broken while upgrading tomcat9

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, tomcat9

Currently I am using tomcat7 and everything is working properly. I did not change anything. When I deploy spring web application then I am facing following errors

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
```

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of
```

I am having following spring and hibernate jar dependencies

```
simple-spring-memcached-3.6.1.jar
spring-amqp-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-cache-3.6.1.jar
spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-solr-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-hateoas-0.11.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-rabbit-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-oauth2-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-core-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-xml-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-4.2.5.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar
```

Apache Maven 3.8.5

Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK

Answer (score 0):

Please check what type are you trying to set/update.
The Reflection is used to match a setter for this property.
Maybe you are trying to set an integer on an String for example?

> A problem occurred accessing a property of an instance of a persistent
> class by reflection, or via CGLIB. There are a number of possible
> underlying causes, including
>
> failure of a security check an exception occurring inside the getter
> or setter method a nullable database column was mapped to a
> primitive-type property the Hibernate type was not castable to the
> property type (or vice-versa)

[read more about this error](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/PropertyAccessException.html)

Comment: I guess this is not the case . main question is how it is working with tomcat7 ?